# 404 Not Found exception handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller that, in case there is no user with the given name, will return 404 NOT FOUND.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/profile/{username}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public HttpEntity<User> getUsers(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
    User user = userService.findOneByUsername(username);

    if(user != null) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Then I created a controller that will be able to handle this exception

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class ExceptionHandlerController {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ModelAndView handleNotFound(NoHandlerFoundException e) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/signIn");
    }
}
```

However, it has no effect. The controller returns the normal default 404 error page. It does not respond to my controller.

EDIT: I set `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found = true`, but that also did not help. I'm using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

You're not throwing NoHandlerFoundException in your controller. This way the ControllerAdvice will not run.

Comment: In which case can I handle it and change page on my?

Comment: Acoording to your code, your controller seems to be from an API and it will return either 200 or 404. Nothing else. To get your exception handler working, throw new NoHandlerFoundException() instead or returning NOT_FOUND.